# Can I get an attribute of a div after hover without initiating the hover itself?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get the height of a div with unknown content after hover without initiating the hover itself?

Could jquery help here?

```css
.content-container{
  width:20%;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.content-container:hover{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">Some content that can be anything of any length</div>
```

Comment: cant understand your question

Comment: i seems you want that height for some css purpose, or some feature already loaded when we hover your div, but if you explain your real problem, i'm sure there is a prettier css way do achieve what you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something to make the rule apply, take the measurement, then remove that something. One easy way is to update the rule to also apply with a class, then add the class, measure, remove the class:

```js
var container = $(".content-container");
var unexpanded = container.height();
console.log("height when unexpanded: " + unexpanded);
container.addClass("expand");
var expanded = container.height();
container.removeClass("expand");
console.log("height when expanded: " + expanded);
```

```css
.content-container{
  width:20%;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.content-container:hover, .content-container.expand {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">Some content that can be anything of any length</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That measures the first/only `.content-container`. If you have multiple, you'll need an `each` loop:

```
$(".content-container").each(function() {
    var container = $(this);
    // ...
});
```